# mangopay intergation in node js. Could not create user

Tags: node.js

I am integrating mangopay in node js and I am using npm for mangopay2-nodejs-sdk.but when I use `api.Users.create` function for creating user ,it gives me error

```
Debug: internal, implementation, error 
TypeError: Uncaught error: Cannot read property 'userClass' of undefined
at Service.extend.create (/home/hashir/artpaie/artapieapp/artapieBackend/node_modules/mangopay2-nodejs-sdk/lib/services/Users.js:38:41)
```

Answer (score 1):

The error handler in _getUserApiAndClass method seems not to be working, my problem was that I didn't have specified the PersonType.

It is uppercase

- Natural: 'NATURAL'
- Legal: 'LEGAL'